# Elasticsearch: Search multiple documents by an array property

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch with Symfony 4. This is my first attempt.

My index: When I run,

```
GET app_file_dev/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

I got,

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "app_file_dev",
        "_type": "file",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": 5,
          "tags": [
            "blue"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "app_file_dev",
        "_type": "file",
        "_id": "8",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": 8,
          "tags": [
            "blue",
            "green"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "app_file_dev",
        "_type": "file",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": 6,
          "tags": [
            "green"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "app_file_dev",
        "_type": "file",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": 7,
          "tags": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to search by that tags field which is an array type.

And then if I run,

```
GET app_file_dev/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "tags": {
        "query": "blue"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can successfully get the two documents with a tag 'blue'.

If I run,

```
GET app_file_dev/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "tags": {
        "query": "blue green",
        "operator": "or"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expected it to return that No.8 file which has tags 'blue' and 'green'.

But no matter if it's 'or' or 'and'. I only got an empty array.

Is there anything wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you're looking for is a query string? try this one out

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type'  => 'my_type',
    'size'  => 10,
    'body'  => [
        "query" => [
            "query_string" => [
                "default_field" => "my_field",
                "query" => "blue OR green"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$search = $client->search($params);
$hits = $search['hits']['hits'];
```

The code snippet above will look for data in your `my_index` -> `my_type` index, focus on the `my_field` that has the KEYWORDS **blue** or **green** now

You may refer more details about query string here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried "query" => "blue AND green" and "query" => "blue OR green", and both worked as I expected. However, when I tried "query" => "blue green", "default_operator" => "AND", I got an empty result. Can I ask how should I use the "default_operator" field?

Comment: it's because if you have a "query" and "default_operator" every SPACE there is in your "query" will be replaced or added with what you have in your "default_operator" that's why I don't usually use it, for example: you have a "default_operator" of OR, then in your "query" you have "blue AND green", it would result to "blue OR AND OR green", hope you understood. here's the reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

if you found my answer helpful, kindly upvote or mark my answer as correct one, thank you very much! :)

Comment: The issue is I didn't add AND between the two words, "query" => "blue green", "default_operator" => "AND", but it seems the 'default_operator" didn't replace the space as I expected.

Comment: ok my bad for that one, but let me clarify 1. What is your purpose of using the "default_operator"? the word itself "blue green" is already read as "blue AND green" coz white space in query string is considered as AND 2. what version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Thanks, man. I'm using "6.3.2". I was trying to fix a bug written by my predecessor, so I hope I can find the root cause, instead of explicitly adding 'AND/OR' to the query string.

Comment: may I know the reason why you don't want to explicitly add AND/OR? it's actually the best practice of elasticsearch for finding keywords in your articles or data

Comment: Finally, I found the cause is that I defined the tags as keyword datatype and it's not analyzed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with array field and you want the document which has both `blue` and `green` you have you use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) in a filter/must clause of bool query as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tags": "blue"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "tags": "green"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In case you want to find the documents which has either green or blue or both as the tags then you can make use of [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html). The query then will be as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "tags": [
              "blue",
              "green"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't simply use the filters as in the real case, we need to search by multiple fields, so if I put them as filters, then if no match on `tags`, the result will be empty.

Comment: You can always switch between `filter`, `must`, `should` clause or any combination of them as per you needs.